# How do I wrap my drawings around a circle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to wrap my drawings around a circle. I tried using the warp tool but I could not make it work the way I wanted it to.

I want to take this drawing...

[image]

and wrap it around a circle like this (but obviously better)...

[image]

Comment: Better how? Looks wrapped around a circle to me

Comment: Not quite, the flags are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

- Divide your flag strip to 2 rectangular parts that both have 8 flags.
- select one 8 fag strip
- make a half circle Goto Object > Envelope Distort > Make with warp > Arc, horizontal, 100% bend, no distortion
- repeat with another strip, select bend=-100%
- align your half-circles, unite them
- epand, add the wanted stroke
- rotate to wanted angle

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried this and it does not work. When I put them together it does not make a perfect circle.

Comment: @IhsanQ the half strips must have absolutely same pixel dimensions. The long flags must be shortened, but only those that have rectangular pattern. Resizing is absolutely no. Even then the result resembles a polygon. To fix that add vertical distortion when warping and cut the extras of by circular clipping mask. This would be easier if you had high quality vector flags.

Answer (score 0):

Drag flag strip to the **Brush Panel**.

When asked choose **Art Brush**

Draw a circle, click the new brush you just made.